# Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2 prompt macro for date

Tags: cognos-10

Using Cognos 10.2.2 Report Studio, I have created a summary report that shows Running Total # Customers and Total # Customers per day.  I then got a second request to have the report default to showing the last 7 days.

I created a prompt macro so that when the report is open, it displays the last 7 days by default but offers a prompt selection if the user wants to run for a specific date range.

I used this prompt macro which seems to work:

```
[Date Enrollment] between #prompt ('Start Date', 'date', '[Start Date Current Week]')# and #prompt ('End Date', 'date', '[End Date Current Week]')#
```

However, the user wants the Running Total # Customers to show running total from beginning date enrollment to last date enrollment - not the last 7 days.

With this macro, the running total is just showing for the dates displayed on the chart.  She does want Total # Customers per day to default to last 7 days (which is why I created the macro), but have the ability to change to start and end dates.

I've attached an image of the report.  The yellow bars are for # customers enrolled on the specific date.  The blue bar currently provides a running total for just the days displayed on the chart.  The request is that the running total, by default show ALL enrollment dates (data currently goes back to May 2018) with the # customer enrollment show the total enrollment by day.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJfCW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this issue because you are filtering the query feeding the chart to exclude all records except for the days provided in the prompt. For a running total to work across all values then all values have to be present when the calculation occurs. The filter prevents this.

There is a solution. You have to use a nested query. This is equivalent to using a subquery or CTE in SQL. Here are the steps:

1. Take the existing query and remove the filter you describe above
2. Go into your list of queries
3. Drag over a new query
4. Drag the original query to the right of the new query, if done right you should see an arrow between from the original query to the new query
5. Open the new query
6. Drag over the fields from the source (original) query that you want to report on
7. Add the filter you used before
8. Go to the report page
9. Select the chart
10. Change the Query property to point to the new query

As an explanation, think of the output of the source query. Without the filter, it now outputs customers and running total per day for every day in the database. Once both these numbers are calculated at the day level we can filter it down to just the days the user cares about at the higher level query.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation is clear and I believe I understand how your suggestion should work.  However,  following these steps the values that are returned are much higher than they should be.  I'll go back over my calculations.  The 'source' query only contained the data items I used on the chart or were needed for the filter.  I copied all the columns to the new query and removed the date prompt macro from the 'source' query and added it to the new query.  I'll dig in and investigate further. Thank you!

Comment: The key is to generate your two aggregates (daily count and running count) at the 'source' query. They are calculated there and the filter applied at the higher-level query. The grain of the queries should be the same. You can also set the Aggregate Function of the aggregate data items in the higher-level query to 'None'. Since they are already calculated, they should not be further aggregated. I'd do a mock up report and post screen shots but I currently don't have access to a Cognos enivornment and am only going on memory.

Comment: Chart displays Ttl # Customers/Day and Running Ttl #  based on the first date in the bar chart. Would like to see is the running ttl for 02-22-19 be the total enrolled on 02-22-19 plus the total running count prior to 02-22-19.  For example, if ttl enrollments through 02-21-19 is 5,426 would like to see 2-22-19 running ttl # customers as 5,426 + 604 (enrolled on March 22.) I’m using a prompt macro [Date Enrollment] between #prompt ('Start Date', 'date', '[Start Date Current Week]')# and #prompt ('End Date', 'date', '[End Date Current Week]')#

Comment: What I described should support your requirement. The running totals are calculated in the lower-level query and the filtering happens at the higher level.